# Explode a comma-delimited string into an array without breaking up double quoted substrings

Tags: php, string, csv, explode, delimited

Suppose that I have this string:

```
var1, var2, var3, "var4, test, test2", var5, "var6", var7
```

How can I use explode() function to put them into an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => var1
    [1] => var2
    [2] => var3
    [3] => var4, test, test2
    [4] => var4
    [5] => var6
    [6] => var7
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think `str_getcsv()` is the function you are looking for; it should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [str_getcsv](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function:

```
$array = str_getcsv('var1, var2, var3, "var4, test, test2", var5, "var6", var7');
```